# How to read Kendo Dropdownlist from controller action in Jquery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I try to read Kendo Dropdownlist from controller action in Jquery. The code is

```
$("#CountryName").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Description",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "Shared/CountryAjax"
            }
        }
    }
});

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CountryAjax(string countryId)
{
    var countries = this._decodeBL.GetAllCountriesList();

    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Description", "Canada")
    };
}
```

But it never executes CountryAjax. I need help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found two bugs from your code. Firstly, you should use [HttpGet] annotation in your server method. Secondly, you shouldn't receive countryId in your server method.

See the fixed code below.

```
$("#CountryName").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Description",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "Shared/CountryAjax"
            }
        }
    }
});


[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CountryAjax()
{
    var countries = this._decodeBL.GetAllCountriesList();

    return new JsonResult
    {
        Data = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Description", "Canada")
    };
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is still not working. DropDownList is not even shown up. Is url right? I have seen that url.content used. I doubt url may be wrong.

Comment: Do you need to use jsonp instead of json? If you are using jsonp, the server needs to be configured for it and url must point to that server.

Comment: I suspect that your url is wrong. I'd recommend you to change jsonp -> json and inspect your http traffic using Chrome developer tools or Fiddler.

Comment: jsonp or json do not make difference, I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#selectYears").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        //dataSource: data2,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetYears", "NewHome")'
                }
            }
        },
        index: 0,
        change: onChange
    });

   return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new SelectList(years, "newHomeIndexid", "selectedYear"),
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.